# How do you insert code into the sidebar?

Tags: functions, actions, sidebar

I would like to add code to the top of the sidebar.

When I do:

```
add_action('get_sidebar', 'function')
```

It adds above the sidebar DIV. I would like to insert inside the DIV.

If I do:

```
add_action('dynamic_sidebar', 'function')
```

It goes in between every single widget and inside all widget areas.

I just want to add some code above all widgets in the right or left sidebar.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you mean you want to modify the sidebar template? You may use child theme and create your own sidebar. What kind of effect do you like to achieve?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I want to insert AdSense code into the sidebar. However, I run multiple sites, and don't want to alter multiple themes. I made a plugin that inserts Adsense into the header, footer, and below the content. But I'd like one more ad in the sidebar.

Comment: Is all the sites using the same theme? Because if theme using get_sidebar(), usually it acquire sidebar.php from the template if available. If none of the template have the sidebar, it fetch the system default one. So, it depends on your structure. If same theme for all, can placing do_action and use add_action in central control etc. So, if you could provide more information such as same theme or not or theme's structure etc, an appropriate strategy could be suggested.